# Python SQL entry not returing search result

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have been having trouble inserting mixed character string into sql db.
I figured urlencoding the string is a easier way to save the string in table.

IE

```
INSERT INTO metadb (name, type , year ) values ( 'Valentine%27s Day', 'movie', '2010')
```

My problem is when I try to look up for this entry with the sql, it is returning nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM metadb WHERE name = 'Valentine%27s Day' and year = '2010' and type = 'movie'
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem? My best guess is that it has something to do with the '%' which is messing it up.

Python SQL platform is used.

Comment: (i) using parameterized queries would have obviated this problem `c.execute("insert... values (%s, %s, %s)", ("Valentine's day", ...)`  (ii) the way to quote `'` in sql is to double it: `insert .. values ('Valentine''s day', ..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldn't be possible for you to split this up? For example, you could do something like this:

```
import urllib2

def main():
    # omitted all the connection stuff...
    query = "INSERT INTO metadb (name, type , year ) values ( %s, %s, %d)"
    params = (escape_string("Valentine's day"), "movie", 2010)
    cursor.execute(query, params)

def escape_string(str):
    return urllib2.quote(str).replace("%","%%")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then the select you have to escape the string, from the documentation:

"Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to execute() must be escaped, i.e. %%."

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

I hope it helps you.

//Daniel

Comment: The initially Entered data had 'Valentine%27s Day' as I was using urlencoding.

Comment: Since I already have plenty of data entered into sql with urlencoding as I have mentioned in the question many of the entries now have the special character %. Now if i am to find the way I have mentioned what modification to str is required is the key factor...any thoughts?

Comment: Try to prepare your string like so : `urllib2.quote("Valentine's day").replace('%','%%')` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your predicate with the `\` character like this:

```
SELECT * FROM metadb WHERE name = 'Valentine\%27s Day' and year = '2010' and type = 'movie'
```

Your guess is right. `%` is a [special character in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html). Also, I would maybe consider using url decoding/encoding library before inserting records into your table.

Comment: I am trying to get a result with this example..thanks